# SCSS compiles correctly to CSS file, but doesn't update styles

Tags: sass

Really trying to get the hang of this. It's probably something really simply, and really stupid. So please just address the issue at hand.

I started my portfolio website over because I could not get the responsive design figured out. I had went through media queries from 320px all the way to 2560px and it looked good at 320, so I went on to the next query and so on and so on. I finished the last at 2560px. I clicked to check my work and clicked 320px again through 768px. Everything was broken. So i researched about CSS grid, and decided to start over and try again.

I started using SASS during my learning process on my last attempt. I liked it. I realized i had to precompile it and such, have used the SASS --watch SCSS/SASS:SCSS/CSS   it watches me SCSS folder which has the SASS folder and the styles.scss I am working on. it then compiles it to SCSS/CSS/styles.css

I can see the green text "Compiled SCSS\SASS\styles.scss to SCSS\CSS\styles.css."
So I can see that that step is working. Next I can see the CSS code being populated in the CSS folder under styles.css

Furthermore, I can see the live reload is working by changing the title text for example and seeing the text change correctly with the live reload.

Here's the code. Any help is appreciated. I am determined to get this. I know I am going to go over a ton of stupid questions till I figure it out. Looks like CSS grid will help. I just don't understand what I did wrong since I had SASS working correctly before.

```css
// SCSS code 
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.skills-container {
    border: 1rem solid black;
    background-color: red;
}
.technical-skills-h1 {
    color: red;
}

// Sections

#technical-skills-section-container {
    background-color: red;
}

/* CSS code */
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.skills-container {
  border: 1rem solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
.technical-skills-h1 {
  color: red;
}

#technical-skills-section-container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Kyle LeBlanc Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="text/scss" href="./SCSS/SASS/styles.scss">
        <link rel="text/css" href="./CSS/stylesheet/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-container">
                <!--This is the container and lists for the menu bar and links to various things  -->
                <div class="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="navbar ">
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="d-block" href="About.html"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="d-block" href="https://github.com/tiberiusnero560?tab=repositories" target='_blank'><strong>Github</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="d-block" href="Resume.html"><strong>Resume</strong></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="d-block" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kylejordenleblanc/" target='_blank'><strong>LinkedIn</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </nav>



    <section id="technical-skills-section-container">
            <div class="skills-title-container">
                <div class="skills-title"">
                    <h1 class="technical-skills-h1">Technical Skills</h1>
                    <p>Languages & Technologies</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!--Container for the 3 panel skills section  -->
            <div class="skills-container">
                
                    <!--The Center Column of the 3 panel layout -->
                    <div class="column-center ">
                            <div class="list-div">
                                <ul class="unordered-list">
                                    <h2 class="skills-title-h2">Web Development & Backend</h2>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">HTML</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">CSS</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">JavaScript</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">PHP</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">MySQL</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--The Left Column of the 3 panel layout  -->
                    <div class="column-left ">
                            <div class="list-div">
                                <ul class="unordered-list">
                                    <h2 class="skills-title-h2">Software Development</h2>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">C++</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">Python</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">C#</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>             
                    </div>

                    <!--The Right Column of the 3 panel layout -->
                    <div class="column-right ">
                        <span class="skills-text-area">
                            <div class="list-div">
                                <ul class="unordered-list">
                                    <h2 class="skills-title-h2">Frameworks & Libraries</h2>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">React</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">JQuery</li>
                                    <li class="ListGroup">Bootstrap</li>   
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
     </section>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and remove unnecessary whitespace in your CSS

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to include your folder structure to get a definitive answer, but probably the link to your CSS is just wrong. Check your browser console to see if there's a 404 error for the stylesheet. In your question, you mentioned the CSS is saved to `SCSS/CSS/styles.css`, but that's not what the `href` on your `<link>` is. Also, no need to include a `<link>` for the SCSS. The browser can't do anything with that. (And even if it could, it'd be redundant.)

Comment: Appreciate the answers. I knew I would butcher the post, I have not used Stackoverflow much but trying to utilize it more to get an understanding. I will keep in mind whitespace for future posts and take a look at my code again. It's likely something silly like you said about it being linked incorrectly. I didn't know i didnt' have to link the SCSS so that is useful to know thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knew it was something silly. But I am fine with reaching out for help as more should be.

For anyone else who has a similar issue. It's stupid, it's basic, and once you figure it out, you won't do it again ! haha. I know I won't.

Your folder structure is everything. As a user pointed out, I had not shown that first and foremost. That is where I should have started searching.

I somehow had a second folder in the root named CSS with the styles correctly compiled. However I had been so narrow in my view of only working with the SCSS/CSS folder I had created and thought I had linked correctly. Always double check the folder structure. Expand all folders and get a real understanding of all your folders and what is where. That certainly helped me once I knew where to look.

Once I linked the stylesheet correctly,
Bang, the colors I had set appeared instantly.

I hope this helps someone else like me. Never be afraid to ask for help. Never be afraid to feel stupid, or inferior. You aren't. You're learning that's what matters.